# Как организовать хронологическую базу данных?

Tags: java, база-данных, swing

Господа, помогите мне, молодому новичку, логически понять, как организовать базу данных.

Ситуация такая:
пишу на java swing, имею таблицу, которая заполняется данными из data[][], ну и соответственно в неё также можно записывать данные.

Еще имеется несколько JComboBox, при помощи которых выбирается дата (date).

То есть мне нужно запоминать, что было записано в определенный день в таблицу и, при необходимости, восстановить эту таблицу.

Можете проконсультировать, как это лучше всего сделать, пожалуйста?

Comment: Например, первый столбец в таблице бд это id - записи, второй - дата, третий - форматирования строка (поле типа text) с данными матрицы, например такая 1,2,3;4,5,6;7,8,9 соответвенно точка с запятой это разделитель строк матрицы, а запятая столбцов

Comment: @AlexanderChernin спасибо :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте использовать Event Sourcing Pattern

Это мощный и интересный подход, при котором сама модель (в данном случае ваша таблица) в общем не храниться и не изменяется. А есть append-only база событий, которые происходили с вашей моделью в хронологическом порядке. События не могут изменяться или удаляться, они могут только добавляться, это сильно упрощает всю логику работы, особенно если ваше приложение будет чуть сложнее.

Применив все имеющиеся события к исходной модели (пустой таблице), вы получите последнее актуальное состояние (проекцию) на настоящий момент, а если события с начала и до момента Х - проекцию на момент Х. Таким образом вы сможете не только получить состояние на любой момент Х, но и при необходимости выяснить почему оно именно такое и какие события к этому привели.

Вам лишь надо выяснить какие события могут происходить с вашей моделью (скорее всего это стандартный CRUD, чтение хранить конечно не надо, хроняться только события изменяющие модель), уметь их складывать в некий список (базу) и применять по необходимости.

При этом нет жесткой необходимости хранить сами проекции, ведь любую из них вы можете получить в любой момент времени. Разумно иметьо кэш наиболее востребованных (например актуальное состояние на текущий момент), но не более.